# Reconstruction of a function from its moments

Tags: real-analysis, integral-transforms

The n-th moment of a real valued function $f$ is defined as:
$m_n(f)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^nf(x)dx$. I heard that a function $f$ is uniquely determined by its moments. I would be quite surprised if this worked for any $f$. Is it true? And in that case, does anyone know how to re-build $f$ from its moments?

Thanks

Comment: For $m_n(f)$ to be defined for all $n$, certainly $f$ must decay faster than the reciprocal of any polynomial, which is a very strong condition. Certainly restricting $f$ to functions in the Schwartz space is sufficient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space .

Comment: I'm not sure about this if you integrate on all of $(-\infty,\infty)$, but if you are integrating over some finite interval, $[a,b]$, and $f$ is continuous, then yes, $f$ is determined by its moments.

This is a classic problem in undergraduate analysis: to use the Weierstrass approximation theorem to show that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b x^n f(x)\ dx=0$ for all natural numbers $n$, then $f=0$. (Can you see that this implies that the moments of a function are unique, by linearity of integration?)

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to reconstruct $f$ then?

Comment: This answer seems to give all the necessary information https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1029178/269624

Answer (score 2):

One example of nonuniqueness was found (I think)  by Stieltjes in 1894:  The function
$$ f(x) = \cases{x^{-\ln(x)} \sin(2\pi \ln(x))& $x > 0$\cr 0 & otherwise} $$
has all its moments $0$.

EDIT: The proof of this is a nice exercise in integration and symmetry. Start with the change of variables $x = \exp(t)$...